# NSDateFormatter date short style has different values

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a single dateFormatter:

```
private lazy var dateFormatter : DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    return formatter
}()
```

Then I pass to it some date, say:

```
let str = self.dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

And I receive different string formats in different cases, for example, I can see a string like 05.24.17 or 5/24/17. 
My question: does it depend on current locale or device settings or smth else?

Thanks.

Comment: yes, depends on the device locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the `DateFormatter` uses the current `Locale` to determine the exact date format to use for the `.short` style. However, you can vend consistently formatted dates if you so wish. To do so, you'll have to set the `Locale` explicitly for the date formatter as shown in this playground snapshot:

[image]